# OSX Docker Build: How can I see the full build output? (--progress=plain not the solution!)

Tags: macos, docker, terminal, dockerfile, docker-build

I just got a MacBook from work and I am using it to build docker images. Usually, the docker build shows the full log (i.e. `ls -la` showing the cwd). Thats at least what I'm used to from my linux machine.

On the macbook however, it only shows a brief overview: (actual console output)

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 40B                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:stretch-slim                                                                                                                                                                        1.1s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 58B                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [1/16] FROM docker.io/library/debian:stretch-slim@sha256:eb436e834ba416c45359aa0709febef17fdea65ab6a8f4db12016aa2fa63be0c                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [2/16] RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [3/16] RUN apt-get install wget -y                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [4/16] RUN wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-5.7.22-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.gz                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [5/16] RUN tar -zxvf mysql-5.7.22-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.gz                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [6/16] RUN mv mysql-5.7.22-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64 mysql-5.7.22                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [7/16] RUN ls -la                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [8/16] RUN mv mysql-5.7.22 /usr/local/                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [9/16] RUN groupadd mysql                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [10/16] RUN useradd -r -s /sbin/nologin -g mysql mysql -d /usr/local/mysql                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [11/16] RUN chown -R mysql /usr/local/mysql-5.7.22/                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [12/16] RUN chgrp -R mysql /usr/local/mysql-5.7.22/                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [13/16] COPY my.cnf /etc/                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [14/16] COPY startup.sh .                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [15/16] RUN ls -la                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:d93a0842352d0980be6ba4b57fdd6cad18818b7527bedecfb706e416b7fb6062                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/customsql
```

Steps 7 and 15 are supposed to show me the results, but this is just omitted. (I know, its the cached result, but it didn't show up, when  I changed the Dockerfile and rebuild the layer as well).

setting `--progress=plain`  didn't do any good. In fact it just changed the color from purple to white (HideThePainHarold.jpg).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer myself: apparently Docker build on OSX is automatically configured to use BuildKit, which disguises a lot of the default debug output.

I removed the option `{"buildkit": true}` from `daemon.json` config file and it works.

Comment: Thank you this saved my butt. Without the default build output it's hard to debug complex steps in the docker-build process.

Comment: Removed what exactly? Which json? daemon.json?

Comment: @chocalaca It's the option {"buildkit": true} in daemon.json. On MacOs you can find it now under Docker desktop icon (whale) -> preferences -> Docker Engine.

Comment: @user3361462 Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Just set export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 in your shell....

Comment: If you are using buildx for multi-arch work - then this wont work.   Instead use this env var... export BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain

Comment: I cannot remember in 2021, but in 2023 the `plain` format is quite verbose, typically 3 lines for each line, as it logs a line, a hash, and a done message. `BUILDKIT_PROGRESS` is [either](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/env-vars/#buildkit_progress) `auto` (default), `plain` or `tty`, none of them gets back the former behaviour of "simple" plain output. A pity or missing something?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [Simons Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66664355/3288890), if you are looking for permanent setting.

To disable docker BuildKit by default, set daemon configuration in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` feature to true and restart the daemon:

```
{ "features": { "buildkit": false } }
```

[image]